# TABLE HTML -> How can I change the way it is done?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, html-table

I am trying to make a table with checkboxes on every row of the table.

I got an example(Code Example link), but I am not being able to get it done. I do not want to use the "data-url" as a source of the table. Except that, everything is accordingly with what I need.

I want to feed the "tbody" by myself.

Here is the example I am following:  [Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/30/)

What I want to accomplish:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <!-- I do not know what to put over here in order to get it working-->
        <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>666</td>
        <td>6969</td>
        <td>Let there be rock</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```html
<!-- UPDATING CODE!  -->


<table data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="bs-checkbox " data-field="state">
            <div class="th-inner">
                <input name="btSelectAll" class="selectall" type="checkbox">
            </div>
            <div class="fht-cell"></div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox ">
                <input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td style="">bootstrap-table</td>
            <td style="">526</td> <td style="">122</td>
            <td style="">Huehuehue</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox ">
                <input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td style="">bootstrap-table</td>
            <td style="">528</td> <td style="">122</td>
            <td style="">huehuheheuhe</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE NOTES**

Now I can feed the "tbody" by myself (thanks to @Adriano Silva), but the "select all" checkbox is not working.

**DONE**

Example of the solution given by @AdrianoSilva:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6fxyn1jr/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a row as example below

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" data-url="none">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="bs-checkbox " data-field="state">
            <div class="th-inner">
                <input name="btSelectAll" type="checkbox">
            </div>
            <div class="fht-cell"></div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox ">
                <input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td style="">bootstrap-table</td>
            <td style="">526</td> <td style="">122</td>
            <td style="">An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3)</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice! 
But now the "select all" checkbox is missing.

Image: https://imgur.com/a/u7gHB [

Comment: Sorry, I meant wrong. The "select all" checkbox is *not* missing, but it is not doing it's functionality: selecting all checkboxes.

Comment: Is there any JS involved in this situation? I've found some problems related to this one and it was used JS to solve it. But it did not went successful on my case.